# Adding more RAM to Gigabyte GA-P35-DS4 rev. 1.0 makes it extremely slow

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard, hardware-failure, memtest86+

**Summary:** Using the motherboard mentioned at the title, adding the DDR2 modules (from 4 GB to 8 GB) caused extreme slowdown. Memtest86+ reveals that probably reading the upper 512 MB works, but is extremely slow. Where to start fixing it?

**Details:** The computer uses `Gigabyte GA-P35-DS4 rev. 1.0` motherboard (about the year 2007), and uses one pair of memory slots with a 2x2 GB DDR2 (before the upgrade). The motherboard should be able to work with another 2x2 GB, so it seemed to be as an easy task.

I have decided to buy two new kits of 2x2 GB RAM on 800 Mhz DDR2 to avoid problems with mixing different memories in the two pairs of slots -- see details below.

When starting the OS (Windows 7) it looked it will start hours. The Memtest86+ version 5.01 was then used for testing...

When using only one new DDR2 kit in the pair of memory slots used earlier, the behaviour was the same as with the old DDR2 kit (one kit 2x2 GB). The Windows started about the same, the memtest took about the same time. The same was observed when the new DDR2 kit was inserted to the other slot of the motherbord (that is one kit 2x2 GB again, but now in the other slots). Also, the old memory kit worked the same way in the other slot.

The second new DDR2 kit was tested the same way and no errors were found. This way I believe that both new DDR2 kits and the old DDR2 kit work correctly and the problem is related to the motherboard.

**Strange observation:** After inserting both new DDR2 kits to the slots (i.e. all memory slots are used, and 8 GB installed), the memtest default testing took almost 3 hours (in comparison to about 20-30 minutes with the half memory). No errors were reported, but when testing the memory range near the end, it run really slowly (visible when observing the "State: x Running..." indicator at the left of the screen). The *slow* range of memory was marked as `8192 M - 8704 M   512 M of 8191 M` (at the right of the screen).

**What should I try?** Is it a known problem? What should I try to make it work? I may find 2x1 GB kit somewhere. If it is a known problem, should I work around with the total 6 GB as a tradeoff? Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Info on memory sticks:** The older kit of memories was Kingston HyperX Limited Edition (KHX8500D2BK2/4G Kit of 2, 2.2V (other info is 99U5316 - 057.A00LF, 0000004607745, HYJUR-999CHM-TW6TF).

The new memory kits are Zeppelin 2G8001288 UL CL6 by www.evolveo.eu (some other numeric info that I know nothing about are 1014 001A21C2 ZPXTL488535). That is, I have two times 2x2 GB, as two kits.

Comment: Please, can you comment on why downvoting?

Comment: I think the downvotes are because you wrote a long story but you could summarize the above to ask a more direct question. Is your memory in the supported memory list for your mobo?

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS to the latest version?

Comment: @EricF: Thanks for the idea. I have rewritten the question. No, the kits are not in the supported memory list as the exact manufacturer. But it says it supports DDR2 1066*/800/667 memory up to 8GB by 4 DIMM slots. The Memory support list does not contain any 2GB DIMMs. The Kingston KHX8500D2K2/1GN is there (half capacity than the old used kit). The Zeppelins may not even existed at the time.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I will check it tomorrow (not having the machine here).

Comment: Well a lot of times if it is not in the list then they won't work. Not to say this is true always, but quite often. It could come down to a timing issue as well.

Comment: @EricF: When using 4 GB of the same memory modules, it works without problem. Only when 8 GB is used, the problem appears.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: There is a newer BIOS at the manufacturer's page. Thanks for the hint. I will flash it probably tomorrow.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Thanks. The newer BIOS fixed the problem. Please, formulate a short comment so that I could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading your BIOS to the latest revision offered by your motherboard manufacturer. It may just be a matter of your current BIOS revision not knowing how to handle the timing and/or voltages when all the slots are populated.

Comment: .oʍʇ ʎʇɹnoɟ ʇnoqɐ buıʞɐǝds ʇou .pǝɹǝʌoɔsıpǝɹ ǝq p1noɥs buıɥʇ snoıʌqo ǝɥʇ sǝɯıʇǝɯos .ʇo1 ɐ sʞuɐɥʇ